# scss styles not reflecting after publishing vite-react app as a package

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, vite

I've published a (vite+react-ts) app as npm package, in my component, I import the style like this:
import "./style.scss"
in mu local machin and development mode it works fine, but the styling not reflecting when I use my published package in other apps.

Here is my vite.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
      lib: {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.ts'),
        name: 'my-app-lib',
        fileName: (format) => `index.${format}.js`,
      },
      rollupOptions: {
        external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        output: {
          globals: {
            react: 'React',
            'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          },
        },
      },
      sourcemap: true,
      emptyOutDir: true,
    },
    plugins: [react(), svgr(), dts()],
});
```

My package.json:

```
{
    
    "main": "dist/index.umd.js",
    "module": "dist/index.es.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "exports": {
      ".": {
        "import": "./dist/index.es.js",
        "require": "./dist/index.umd.js",
        "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
      }
    },
    "files": [
      "/dist"
    ],
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "vite && lint",
      "build": "tsc && vite build",
      "preview": "vite preview",
      "lint": "eslint src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}",
      "lint:fix": "eslint --fix src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}"
    },
}
```